# NSPredicate Format String with unexpected result

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I am learning NSPredicate and I have an example with problem.

```
NSArray * array = @[@{@"name":@"KudoCC"}, @{@"name":@"123"}] ;
NSPredicate * predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == '%@'", @123] ;
NSArray * result = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] ;
```

The parameter here is @123, it is `NSNumber` type. I think it works the same as `@"name == '123'"`, but the result is nil, which I expected as `@{@"name":@"123"}`.

Can somebody tell me why? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001793-208600) said,

> If you use variable substitution using %@ (such as firstName like %@), the quotation marks are added for you automatically.

Quotation marks should be avoided in common cases. If you use something like `@"%K == '%@'"`, you are actually comparing the key with `@"%@"`. Only if you have an array like `@[@{@"%@": @"KudoCC"}]`, you need this way.

Comment: No, it is different. "@"%K == '%@'"
This predicate checks whether the value of the key %K is equal to the string literal “%@“ (note the single quotes around %@). The key name %K is supplied at runtime as an argument to predicateWithFormat:."

Comment: Yea I know, I supposed that you don't want to do this.

Comment: Sorry to misunderstand you , I have edited my question, please help.

Comment: Sorry I still didn't understand, you've already pointed out that "@"%K == '%@'" checks whether the value of the key %K is equal to the string literal "%@". That's true, if you want to bind a parameter, don't add quotation marks.

Comment: I have edited my question, the parameter here is a `NSNumber` and I want to compare it to an string value, that's why I add quotation marks.

Comment: Oh I got it, you may want to convert NSNumber to NSString. Use @"123" or (@123).stringValue, without quotation marks.

Comment: Yes, it will work if I use `NSString`. But I want to know why it can't work if I use NSNumber.

Comment: Because NSPredicate has some magic, it not just simply replaces placeholders with parameters. As non-Apple developers, we don't know what happened exactly inside predicateWithFormat:. So I suggest you just follow the documented way, or the right behavior could not be guaranteed.

Comment: Can you show me some conditions which must using `@"%K == '%@'"`?

Comment: I don't think there are such conditions -- usages like @"%K == '%@'" should be avoided. Use the right type to compare, and NSPredicate will add quotation marks automatically.

Comment: In the document [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pCreating.html), it talks about it in the last paragraph.

Comment: That '%@' is just like 'KudoCC' or any common text, is not for parameter binding. Imagine you have an array ``@[@{@"%@": @"KudoCC"}]``, then you need this way.